# Embedded qtip2 Modal in Fullcalendar + Google Calendar

Tags: jquery, iframe, modal-dialog, fullcalendar, qtip2

I am using FullCalendar 2.3.1, qtip2.2.1 and multiple Google Calendar feeds.

So I finally got my qtips to work in my Fullcalendar (yay!), but now I'd like to see about getting a modal qtip to appear when an event is clicked on ( `eventClick` ).

Currently I have `eventClick` set to:

```
// opens events in a popup window
eventClick: function(event) {
                window.open(event.url, 'gcalevent', 'width=600,height=400,top=200,left=200');
                return false;               
            },
```

I'd like to get a modal to appear instead, with the `event.url` portion embedded within in. qtip2 has modal functionality, and I got that included when I downloaded qtip2, but I just can't seem to figure out how to get the modal part functioning with a page embedded in it. And all the other resources online seem to be specifically with Bootstrap, not qtip2. Or some other plugin.

I know part of it is using qtip's `show:` `modal:` `on: true` and using an iframe. It's just the proper sequence I can't seem to get.

This is the coding I have for my general qtips, so I wasn't sure if there was a way I could modify it to function on `eventClick` instead, and again, with the embedded page for `event.url`

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
if (view.name !== "agendaDay"){
                element.qtip({
                    content: {
                        title: 'Click the event to open it in  <br/>Google Calendar',
                        text: '<b>Title: </b>' + event.title +
                        '<br/><br/><b>Location: </b>' + event.location +
                        '<br/><br/><b>Details: </b>' + event.description
                    },
                style: {
                    widget: true, // Use the jQuery UI widget classes
                    def: false, // Remove the default styling
                    classes: 'qtip-rounded qtip-shadow'
                    },
                position: {
                    my: 'bottom center',
                    at: 'top center'
                    },
                show: {
                    event: 'mouseenter'
                    },
                hide: {
                    event: 'mouseleave',
                    leave: false
                    }
                });
                }
            }
```

Many, many, many thanks in advance! I've spent so much time digging in StackOverflow and it's come to just having to ask. I'm feeling rather foolish and really do appreciate all help.

Comment: Hey Ariel, can you please make a fiddle for it? It looks like [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25379229/how-do-you-use-qtip-modal-on-fullcalendar) has the same requirement as you. Hope it helps.